# Letting an instance of a class search through an array within another class

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, class

I'm new here and don't really know where to put this, but I have the following issue:

I have a class CZombie, which looks like this:

```
{
private:
    int m_Lifepoints;
    int m_PositionX;
    int m_PositionY;
    short m_SunSensetivity;

public:
    CZombie(int Lifepoints, int PositionX, int PositionY, short Sun);
    ~CZombie();
    void SetLifepoints(int Lifepoints);
    int GetLifepoints();
    void SetPositionX(int PosiX);
    int GetPositionX();
    void SetPositionY(int PosiY);
    int GetPositionY();
    short GetSunSensetivity();
    bool virtual FireWeapon(int x, int y) = 0;
    void virtual RevealRole();
    void Find();
};
```

and a class CGarden, which looks like this:

```
#include "CZombie.h"

class CGarden
{
private:
    CZombie* m_Array[7][7];

public:
    CGarden();
    ~CGarden();
    CZombie* ReturnValue(int x, int y);
    void SetField(int x, int y, CZombie* thing);
};
```

in CZombie, there is a member function called Find, which is supposed to search through the two dimensional array in the class CGarden, and stop as soon as it finds a spot thats not a null pointer.

How can I let the Zombie search through the array?

PS: I know that CZombie is abstract, but its child classes have to be able to find the plants in there.

Comment: You might want to reconsider your design, since this smells strongly of a cyclic dependency. Can you refactor your code such that `Find` is part of `CGarden` instead?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your immediate question, `CZombie` will need to be given a pointer or reference to the array to search through so that `Find` can locate it. This could be done either as a raw pointer/reference, a `shared_ptr`, etc. For example:

```cpp
class CZombie {
    ...
public:
    CZombie(CZombie(*zombie_array)[7][7]*, Lifepoints, int PositionX, int PositionY, short Sun);
    ...
}
```

`CZombie(*zombie_array)[7][7]*` is a pointer to a 2D-array of `CZombie*` with each dimension of `7` (as per the `CGarden` class). Note that this pointer does not actually *own* the memory of the array, so if `CGarden` goes out of scope, then accessing this pointer will be undefined behavior.

---

*That said...*

IMO a better approach for this would be to refactor your code such that `CGarden` defines the `Find` logic so that `CZombie` does not have a strong coupling with `CGarden`.

Topologically, the design is more complicated if an inner object requires searching through an outer object's containers, even if that container is shared. If you can refactor so that this isn't the case, this would be cleaner and easier to work with.

Comment: I know where you're going, sadly our professor wanted us to specifically implement the function find in the class CZombie, thank you for your solution tho, highly appreciated.

Comment: Your professor should reconsider his priorities if he wants you to do it that way.